# eclipse workspace with unrecognized code

Tags: eclipse, workspace

How can I delete this unrecognized shadow code?
It has no effect on my code.
But it's very annoying my eyes.

[image]

Comment: Note: reset perspective and change theme. not work for this problem.

Comment: What you call `shadow code` is only the **line terminators**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Just click on **Show Whitespace Characters** button (marked red on picture).